# Social plugin doesn't load only in IE

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-social-plugins

I have a prolem with IE when i using the social facebook plug in.
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" 
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
....
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
...
</body>
```

And when i need to show the social plugin in my page, use this code from facebook

```
<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/MYPAGE" colorscheme="dark" show_faces="true" header="false" stream="false" show_border="false"></fb:like-box>
```

This code work done in Firefox, Chrome, Opera but not on IE11. 
I have tried to use this:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

But, also in this case, IE doesn't show the plugin, all other browser yes.
Why is this??

Comment: did you try the html5 version of the like box too?

Comment: Yes, but nothing has changed, IE doesn't work and other browser yes.

Comment: And what, if anything, does the browser console say? does it say why it's not working?

Comment: Mhh i founded 3 errors on IE console. All errors types are SCRIPT5: access denied. I noticed that if I decrease the security settings of IE the plugin works, but the errors persist.